# iTunes/Applescript: get all tracks from (incomplete) album

Tags: itunes, applescript, album

I try to write an Applescript that would sort playlists by album. That is, a playlist P might contain 20 tracks split on 4 albums (A1, A2…). Each album has 10 tracks, in other words, on this playlist, the albums on average only contain half of the tracks.

I have found a lot of examples where you can query iTunes for all tracks that belong to an album on the library level, typically something like this

```
set albumSongs to (every track of library playlist 1 whose album is currentAlbum)
```

while I want to do something like this

```
set albumSongs to (every track of playlist myPlaylist whose album is currentAlbum)
```

but compiling my example returns an error message *Expected class name but found identifier.* pointing at the *track* keyword in the line above.

Update:

The unfinished function I try to write where I want to get all tracks that belong to a certain album

```
on sortPlaylist(albumList, currentPlaylist)
    repeat with currentAlbum in albumList
        set albumSongs to (every track of currentPlaylist whose album is currentAlbum)
    end repeat
end sortPlaylist
```

It takes a list without duplicates of all albums (`albumList`) and the playlist (`currentPlaylist`) I want to work with. I still have no code to actually sort it (input is appreciated!) but the plan is to sort `albumSongs` in track order and then add the tracks to the playlist in order.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
set playlistName to "playlist name"

tell application "iTunes"
    set playlistReference to first playlist whose name = playlistName
    set currentAlbum to album of current track
    set albumSongs to (every track of playlistReference whose album is currentAlbum)
end tell
```

Comment: Still the same error message.

Comment: Have you tried making a new script and pasting only my code into it?

Comment: I just did and then it works. Surprising. I don't understand what significant difference there is between yours and mine code.

Comment: You never included a tell application "iTunes" block in your handler

Comment: But I have a tell application itunes in the function calling this subroutine. Something like
`tell applictation "itunes"
sortPlaylist (arg1, arg2)
end tell

sortPlaylist (arg1, arg2)
 [your code here]
end`

Doesn't this function inherit the `tell itunes`?

Comment: No... a handler called from within a tell block does not inherit the tell block.

Answer (score 0):

```
set albumSongs to (every track of playlist (name of myPlaylist) whose album is currentAlbum)
```

Comment: Still the same error message.

Comment: could you post more of your code ? It would be easier to help you...

Comment: More code added.

Comment: @adayzdone have found the solution, your handler should be in a tell application "iTunes" block.